# A geometric characterization of quasicircles

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, cv.complex-variables, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal

I'm reading an article by complex analysists.

A Jordan curve $J$ in the extended complex plane $\hat{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ is called a quasicircle if there is a quasiconformal map of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ which maps $J$ onto the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

It is known that the [Koch snow flake](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%83%E3%83%9B%E6%9B%B2%E7%B7%9A#/media/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB:Von_Koch_curve.gif) is a quasicircle.

Ahlfors shows that a Jordan curve $J$ in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is quasicircle iff
\begin{align*}
k(J)=\inf \frac{|z_1-z_3||z_2-z_4|}{|z_1-z_2||z_3-z_4|+|z_1-z_4||z_2-z_3|}>0.
\end{align*}
Here, the infimum is extended to over the set of ordered quadruples $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ of finite points on $J$ with the property that $z_1$ and $z_3$ separate $z_2$ and $z_4$ on $J$.

Note that $k(\text{Koch snow flake})>0$.

**My question**

For what Jordan curves, can we obtain a quantitative estimate for $k(J)$?

It is known that if $J$ is a Euclidean circle or a straight line, $k(J)=1$.

For example. if $J$ is rectangle, $k(J)\ge $?